# Показывать клавиаутуру по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: java, android, клавиатура

Как возможно по нажатию на обычную кнопку открывать системную клавиатуру?

Видел кучу примеров со скрытием и с `EditText`, но не то всё.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```